# Absolute Galois cohomology of function fields (of high-dimensional) varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, galois-theory, galois-cohomology, absolute-galois-group

What is known about the absolute Galois cohomology of function fields of varieties of dimension 2 or larger? Specifically, I am interested in multiplicative coefficients $\mathbb G_m$.

I have seen some results about absolute Galois groups of curves, such as the references in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/users/13265/jason-starr), but nothing for higher dimensional varieties.  The result of Pop that is referenced there concludes that certain function fields of curves have absolute Galois group that is pro-finite free, which certainly has strong implications for the cohomology, but I suspect that these groups can be more interesting when the dimension of the variety is higher.

Are there known connections between the homotopy/cohomology of the variety (thought of as a manifold) and the Galois cohomology, or is that just wishful thinking?

I am happy to consider any base field for the variety, though I suspect the answer will be simpler when the base field is $\mathbb C$ or at least algebraically closed.

Comment: Look at papers by Bogomolov and Tschinkel. Main result in the area is the analogue of Neukirch-Uchida theorem for "big" fields: namely, $k(X)$ for $k$ alg closed of characteristic p and dim $X \geq 2$ is uniquely determined by maximal two-step nilpotent pro-l quotient of its absolute Galois group.

Comment: ...And that basically tells you that cohomology ring of a field (with trivial $\Bbb F_l$ coefficients) remembers the field: this two step nilpotent quotient can be recovered from iterated multiplication map on first cohomology by some weak formality result (there are not enough Massey products to mess it up). So if the variety is defined over the integers, you can recover *all* birational topological invariants.

Comment: As for results directly related to cohomology of big fields, I recommend papers by Ido Efrat, Jan Minaˇc and Claudio Quadrelli; Koszulity of cohomology ring with trivial coefficients has strong implications on the structure of cohomology with coefficients in canonical character module.